# Laravel component class ignore due to component create in different folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-components

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Admin.-newclubform extends Component

{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {echo "demo";
        return view('components.admin.-newclubform');
    }
}
```

[image]

I use `php artisan make:component Admin.Newclubform`
command to create component in Admin Folder.
views section working but class is ignored.

php artisan make:component Admin.Newclubform creates all class and view . class is generated by artisan command
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, `Admin.Newclubform` is not a valid class name you could use in that artisan make command. If you want to namespace the component, you can do `php artisan make:component \\App\\View\\Components\\Admin\\Newclubform`

Comment: The image is not very helpful. Can you please hover the red underlined line and post the tooltip content (error message) as text instead?

Comment: php artisan make:component Admin.Newclubform creates all class and view . class is generated by artisan command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @shaedrich   Admin.Newclubform is not a valid class name.

So creating subfolder run command like below

```
php artisan make:component Admin/NewClubForm
```

This will create file inside

```
App\View\Components\Admin\NewClubForm
```

So your component look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Admin;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class NewClubForm extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.admin.new-club-form');
    }
}
```

then you can access like this

```
<x-admin.newclubform></x-admin.newclubform>
```